# SQL aggregation query corresponding in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate-functions, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-sql

I studied elasticsearch aggregation queries but couldn't find if it supports multiple aggregate function. In an other word, I wanna know if elasticsearch can generate the equivalent of this Sql aggregation query:

```
  SELECT account_no, transaction_type, count(account_no), sum(amount), max(amount) FROM index_name GROUP BY account_no, transaction_type Having count(account_no) > 10
```

If yes, how? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are *two possible ways* to do what you are looking for in ES and I've mentioned them both below.

I've also added sample mapping and sample documents for your reference.

### Mapping:

```
PUT index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs":{
      "properties":{
        "account_no":{
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "transaction_type":{
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "amount":{
          "type":"double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

Notice carefully, I'm only creating list of 4 transactions for 1 customer.

```
POST index_name/mydocs/1
{
  "account_no": "1011",
  "transaction_type":"credit",
  "amount": 200
}

POST index_name/mydocs/2
{
  "account_no": "1011",
  "transaction_type":"credit",
  "amount": 400
}

POST index_name/mydocs/3
{
  "account_no": "1011",
  "transaction_type":"cheque",
  "amount": 100
}

POST index_name/mydocs/4
{
  "account_no": "1011",
  "transaction_type":"cheque",
  "amount": 100
}
```

There are two ways to get what you are looking for:

### Solution 1: Using Elasticsearch Query DSL

**Aggregation Query:**

For Aggregation Query DSL, I've made use of the below aggregation queries to solve what you are looking for.

- [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)
- [Sum Aggregation Query (Metric Aggregation)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html)
- [Max Aggregation Query (Metric Aggregation)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html)

Below is how query is summarised version of the query so that you get the clarity on which queries are *sibling* and which are *parents*.

```
- Terms Aggregation (For Every Account)
  - Terms Aggregation (For Every Transaction_type)
    - Sum Amount 
    - Max Amount
```

Below is the actual query:

```
POST index_name/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "account_no_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "account_no"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "transaction_type_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "transaction_type",
            "min_doc_count": 2
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_amount": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "amount"
              }
            },
            "max_amount":{
              "max": {
                "field": "amount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Important thing to mention is **`min_doc_count`** which is nothing but the `having count(account_no)>10`, which in my query I'm filtering only those transactions with `having count(account_no) > 2`

**Query Response**

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "account_no_agg" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1011",                         <----  account_no
          "doc_count" : 4,                        <----  count(account_no)
          "transaction_type_agg" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "cheque",                 <---- transaction_type
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "sum_amount" : {                  <----  sum(amount)
                  "value" : 200.0
                },
                "max_amount" : {                  <----  max(amount)
                  "value" : 100.0
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : "credit",                 <---- another transaction_type
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "sum_amount" : {                  <---- sum(amount)
                  "value" : 600.0
                },
                "max_amount" : {                  <---- max(amount)
                  "value" : 400.0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the above result carefully, I've added comments wherever required so that it helps what part of sql query you are looking for.

### Solution 2: Using Elasticsearch SQL(_xpack solution)

If you are making use of xpack feature of Elasticsearch's SQL Access, you can simply copy paste the [SELECT Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/sql-syntax-select.html) as below for the mapping and document as mentioned above:

**Elasticsearch SQL:**

```
POST /_xpack/sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "SELECT account_no, transaction_type, sum(amount), max(amount), count(account_no) FROM index_name GROUP BY account_no, transaction_type HAVING count(account_no) > 1"

}
```

**Elasticsearch SQL Result:**

```
  account_no   |transaction_type|  SUM(amount)  |  MAX(amount)  |COUNT(account_no)
---------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------
1011           |cheque          |200.0          |100.0          |2                
1011           |credit          |600.0          |400.0          |2
```

Note that I've tested the query in ES 6.5.4.

Hope this helps!